# Using ng-show in directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-show

I'm trying to accomplish the following behaviour:

1. Looping through an array with `ng-repeat` resulting in table rows.
2. Add an extra hidden row ("details") after each row (can't use several tbody elements)

I made a directive which is an attribute of the `tr` tag. The second row is generated but not hidden. Everything is working as expected, except that `ng-show` isn't working and the "detail" row is displayed.

My directive:

```
'use strict';
app.directive('entryDetails', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            entry: '=',
        },
        link: function(scope,element,attrs) {
            scope.entry.showDetails = false;
            element.after(angular.element('<tr class="entry-details" ng-show="entry.showDetails" id="entry-details-'+scope.entry.id+'"><td colspan="5">Details...</td></tr>'));
        }
    };
});
```

Called via:

```
<tr ng-repeat="entry in  entries track by entry.id" id="entry-{{entry.id}}" entry-details entry="entry">
```

What do I need to do that `ng-show` is working like it would have been in a template?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to `$compile` the second `<tr>`.

```
app.directive('entryDetails', function ($compile) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            entry: '=',
        },
        link: function(scope,element,attrs) {
            scope.entry.showDetails = false;
            var t = '<tr class="entry-details" ng-show="entry.showDetails" id="entry-details-'+scope.entry.id+'"><td colspan="5">Details...</td></tr>';
            element.after(angular.element($compile(t)(scope)));
        }
    };
});
```

This will allow Angular to wire up that `ng-show` and do everything it has to do behind-the-scenes to be aware of it.  Else, Angular doesn't know it exists.